# How I can hide default wordpress sidebar in woocommerce pages?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I want to hide my default blog sidebar in all pages of the woocommerce plugin and instead add woocommerce sidebar.
How in can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's theme dependent. Please check your theme option and see if you can change the sidebar for the WooCommerce page.

For example, this is the theme option in Avada theme:
[image]